# integrating m/s with a double integral

Tags: calculus, integration

If I double integrate $f(x,y)$ with unit $m/s$, will the units become $m, m^2/s$ or $m/s^2$? I know the derivative of $m/s$ is just $m$.

Comment: Are you integrating with respect to length twice, length then time, or time twice?

Comment: this is the question I am givin: https://imgur.com/6LQ80SX

Comment: You're integrating over a cross-sectional area. What do you think your units would be given that?

Comment: @pranavb23 I don't see how you've done $m/s \cdot m \cdot m = m^2/s$, are you sure that power is right?

Comment: oh sorry it should be $m^3$,thank you for pointing it out, ill delete and re comment

Comment: The problem is let $f(x,y)$ be the flow through a particular point on an aqueduct. What are the units of integrated over a particular slice of $\int\int f(x,y)dxdy$ the aqueduct, as pictured? What does this quantity represent?

Comment: its $m^3/s$ and it represents the volume flow rate i think, To find the units of $\int\int f(x,y)dydx$ then just multiply the units of f(x,y),dy and dx

Comment: Discharge is defined as $ Q = v \cdot Area$  making dimension $m/s \cdot m^2 = m^3/s$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I well understand you have a function $f(x,y)$ the has the dimension of a velocity $(m/s)$. The dimension of the integral depends from the dimensions of $x$ and $y$.  ù

As example, if $x$ has the dimension of  space $(m)$ and $y$ has dimension of time $(s)$, when you integrate the terms in the integral is the product of the function and two differential, and this product gives the dimension of the integrated quantity, as in the case:

$
f(x,y)dxdy  
$

but, if $x,y$ are length $(m)$ than $f(x,y)dxdy$ has dimension $(m/s)(m)(m)$

that has dimension $(m/s)(m)(s)=(m^2)= (m^3/s)$

Comment: I don't think $y$ is specified to be time, or a spatial dimension, so the question's missing relevant details.

Comment: The illustration does that there poster is integrating over a cross-sectional area.

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern I think you're probably right that $(x,y)$ are the spatial co-ordinates of the "point" they're talking about. But as far as I can see, they haven't made that explicitly clear

Comment: @Jam:  I modified my answer so that it can give correct hint  ( I hope).